# How to change your xml code if someone presses a button on the xml code in android development?

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, dynamic

I am making a mobile application for android using XML and JAVA.

How can I add another row (of stuff ) to this XML layout when someone presses the button "add".

For example, if they click the button add on this layout.
http://gyazo.com/fe44f0ddbad62d1664a6f3cd8b4a55b9

It will become this: http://gyazo.com/9bc6b27aaf89226b0bcba8cb34c17f5f

So the important part is that the add button moves down, and I am able to modify the XML file to display something new.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't modify the layout files, in the example you have shared, there are a few ways to do it. Either use a `ListView` and add a new item (using an adapter) or you can use a `LinearLayout` and inflate a view and insert it in the `LinearLayout`. These changes are **not** permanent in your layout. You'll need to store this data somewhere and recreate your layout.

Look at how [Building layouts with adapters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews) for example on how to dynamically add content to a view.

The use a `RelativeLayout` to position the button under your `ListView` however when the list grows to the size of the screen this can be problematic before the list can scroll and it takes up the whole screen so there is no way to see anything that has been pushed beyond the screen. So to solve this problem you can either:

- Add the button to the `ListView` footer. This way it will always be at the bottom of your list view and scrolling to the bottom will display the button.
- Use a `RelativeLayout` to position the button absolutely to the bottom of the screen so it will stay there no matter how long the list goes and on click when you add a new item, scroll the `ListView` to the bottom.

I recommend the second approach since it's nicer from a UI point of view. 
Also, I would recommend use using an `ActionBar` add button instead as that is more inline with android user expectations.

Answer (score 0):

in .xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
</LinearLayout>
```

in .java

```
    Button button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
            EditText editTextView = new EditText(MainActivity.this);
            LayoutParams params = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1);
            editTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
            linearLayout.addView(editTextView);

        }});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a view into a empty LinearLayout

or you can set the edittext view.visible or view.gone

or you can set the editext enabled false and the background transparent,when you click the button, set the edittext enabled ture,and set background

there ara many ways to do this